# Existence question about Hamming weights of addition of numbers modulo $2^n-1$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $w_1, w_2$ be given, $1 \leq w_1 \neq w_2 \leq n-1$. Given an integer $a$, $1 \leq a \leq 2^n-2$, can we find $b$, $1 \leq b \leq 2^n-2$, with $W_H(b) = w_1$ and such that $W_H(a + b \mod{2^n-1}) = w_2$?

Here $m \mod 2^n-1$ means the canonical representative of $m$ modulo $2^n-1$, and $W_H(m)$ denotes the Hamming weight of $m$ in its binary representation. I've tried quite a number of experiments and it seems it works. I'm wondering if any of you would know or have seen a proof? Thanks!

**Note:** The original question included the cases $w_1$ or $w_2 = 0$. I have removed these, since the result is false in general here.

Comment: Did you mean $W_H(a+b \mod 2^n)$?  Also, did you mean $0 \leq w_1, w_2 \leq n$?

Comment: Also, did you intend $0 \leq b \leq 2^n -1 $?

Comment: No. I meant exactly mod $2^n-1$. Thus $m \mod 2^n-1 < 2^n-1$; hence $W_H(m \mod 2^n-1) < n$. Here $0 \leq b \leq 2^n-2$.

Comment: However if you have a proof for $\mod 2^n$, it might perhaps work for $2^n-1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true in general.  A counterexample is $n=3$, $w_1 = 0$, $w_2 = 1$, $a=3$.

Here is Python code for finding counterexamples:

```
def wh(b):
    return bin(b).count('1')


def find_counterexamples(n):
    N = 2**n
    for w_1 in range(1, n):
        for w_2 in range(1, n):
            if w_1 != w_2:
                for a in range(1, N-1):
                    for b in range(N-1):
                        if wh(b) == w_1 and wh((a + b) % (N-1)) == w_2:
                            break
                    else:
                        yield w_1, w_2, a
```

**Edit:** Updated such that $w_1, w_2 \geq 0$.  New counterexample: $n=4$, $w_1 = 1$, $w_2 = 3$, $a = 1$.

Comment: Thanks augurar. However I've just realized that the result is clearly not true in general when $w_1 = 0$ or $w_2 = 0$. Indeed, if $w_1 = 0$, then $b = 0$ is the only possibility. Then $W_H(a + b) = W_H(a)$, which clearly may not be $w_2$. Also if $w_2 = 0$, then $W_H(a + b \mod{2^n-1}) = 0$ implies $a + b = 2^n-1$; hence $b =  -a \mod 2^n-1$; thus $W_H(b) = n - W_H(a)$, which may not be $w_1$ (depends only on the weight of $a$)

Comment: Thus I edit the question to not allow for $w_1, w_2$ to be $0$. In fact, all the computer examples I had tried did not involve this case.

Comment: Thank you for putting the time to write the Python code as well!

Comment: @user152169 True, but setting $w_1, w_2$ nonzero doesn't help.  You can play around with the code to test various different constraints, but I don't think you'll find any variant of the claim which is true.  There's no reason to think that a proposition such as this would be true.

Comment: I agree. I wrote some sage code based on what you had above (the python code didn't compile properly on sage for some reason) There were quite a number of counterexamples... maybe there is a bit of pattern to them, but well...